# ng-Grid inside a celltemplate

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, celltemplate

I have created an ng-grid where 2 cells of a column should be another grids. am looking for a cell template that will check 3 conditions on a variable where if the variable is '0' then the cell will be editable, if the value is '1' then the call will be having a grid1 and if the value is '3' then it will be grid 2. Since the data for the grids are dynamic i need to define the cell template and based on conditions the data to the grid inside cell will load. Can anyone suggest me a cell template to the problem? The image of the grid am trying to build is attached.

[image]